# What is the object argument of the returned List if the query is customized?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In general if the `query` is based on a simple entity then the returned `List` is `List<ClassNameOfEntity>`. But now I am doing this query :

```
SELECT tr.trc_id AS id, 
DATE_FORMAT(tr.trc_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS date_,  
DATE_FORMAT(tr.trc_date, '%H:%i:%s') AS heure,  
tr.trc_action AS details, 
CONCAT(IF(u.user_prenom IS NOT NULL, u.user_prenom, '') , ' ', u.user_name) AS noms, 
m.menu_action AS action

FROM trace_acces tr
INNER JOIN utilisateur u ON u.user_id = tr.user_id
INNER JOIN menu m ON m.menu_code = tr.menu_code
```

There are already entities defined for each database tables involved in this query. So what is the argument of the `List` in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get an `List` of `Object[]`

The order in the `Object[]` will match the column order in the select statement.

meaning that `list.get(0)[0]` will be `tr.trc_id` of the first row, `list.get(0)[1]` will be `DATE_FORMAT(tr.trc_date, '%d-%m-%Y')` of the first row, etc...

You can customize the specific type used by hibernate by using `sqlQuery.addScalar(columnAlias, Type);` or `sqlQuery.addEntity(tableAlias, entityName);`

Some examples :

```
"select {r.*}, {t.*}, u.id as u_id from table1 r, table2 t, table3 u ..."
query.addEntity("r", REntityName); // -> row[0]
query.addEntity("t", TEntityName); // -> row[1]
query.addScalar("u_id", Hibernate.LONG); // -> row[2]
// (or StandardBasicTypes.LONG in latest hibernate versions)
```

In your specific case, it seems column are `String` so you'll get an Object[] with `String` in each cells (apart perhaps from the first column).